# Select all elements with same class names as the current event target

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have elements with multiples classes

```
<div id="d1" class="class1 class2"></div>
<div id="d2" class="class1 class2"></div>
```

In an event handler tied to the above divs, I want to select all similar elements i.e. get the class names from the event target and then select all elements that have same class names.

I came up with this: get the `class` attribute & split or replace the space with `.`  It seems a bit crude. Am I missing a jquery feature that readily handles this?

```
classStr      = $(e.currentTarget).attr('class')   

//Method 1 - split at space & prepend dot & join
classSelector = (classStr.split(/\s+/).map(function(v){return '.'+v})).join('')

//Method 2 - Replace space with '.' and prepend '.'
classSelector = '.' + classStr.replace(/\s+/,'.')

desiredElem   = $(classSelector)
```

Comment: replace the space with comma and dot ',.' . Any multi-selector is `$('.class1,.class2')`

Comment: @shaunakde: No, no comma. The goal seems to be to select only elements that have the same classes. `.class1.class2` will select elements that only have both classes; `.class1,.class2` will select elements with *either* class.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/N7e65/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I missing a jquery feature that readily handles this?

I don't think so, no. Your Method #2 is probably the most straight-forward. Note that the class is reflected as `className`, so you don't have to do the `$(e.currentTarget).attr('class')` thing. So:

```
var classSelector = '.' + e.currentTarget.className.replace(/\s+/g, '.');
var desiredElems  = $(classSelector)
```

<s>But beware that IE8 and below don't have `currentTarget`. If you're doing this within a jQuery event handler, you probably want `this`.</s>

```
var classSelector = '.' + this.className.replace(/\s+/g, '.');
var desiredElems  = $(classSelector)
```

*(jQuery supplies `currentTarget` correctly even on IE8 ([live example](http://jsbin.com/buripapo/1)), so if you're in a jQuery event handler, `e.currentTarget` is fine.)*

Comment: As usual, your answers are very informative. Thank you for the extra bit.

Comment: @buffer: FWIW, I don't think there's anything crude about your Method #2. You're transforming one form of a list of classes (the one we use in the `class` attribute) into another form (the one we use for multiple class selectors). Your method #2 is a very straight-forward way to do that.